# External HTML Template interpolation

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular 2.0 and angular in general. I've been digging around for a few days now on this problem, and I can't seem to find a word about it anywhere.  I have a component that calls an external HTML in the TemplateURL as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'Form-template',
  templateUrl: "app/components/HTMLReferences/CommentsForm.html",
  styleUrls: ["app/components/CSSReferences/CommentForm.css"]
  })
```

Nothing crazy here.

Now in my template I need to load an object variable, "frequencies", to populate the drop down box.  The code inside the external HTML template is as follows:

```
 <div class="dropdown">
    <select id="frequency"
            class="form-control"
            #frequency="ngModel"
            ngModel
            required>
      <option value=""></option>
      <option *ngFor="let frequency of frequencies" value="{{ frequency.id }}">
        {{frequency.label}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

again, nothing special.  The object is in the component's export class as follows:

```
export class FormTemplateComponent  {
  frequencies = [
    { id: 1, label: 'Daily' },
    { id: 2, label: 'Weekly' },
    { id: 3, label: 'Monthly' }
  ];
}
```

When I load the page nothing appears in the drop down box. Here's a screen shot:

[image: missing values]

My FromTemplateComponent is also available in the NGModules file under declarations.

I have to be missing something incredibly silly in all this, but I just can't seem to figure it out.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always remember children: when using ngModel, make sure you set the name correctly.

[image: Found the problem]

Answer (score 1):

You should be using property binding as below

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <select id="frequency"
            class="form-control"
            [(ngModel)]="frequency"
            required>
      <option value=""></option>
      <option *ngFor="let frequency of frequencies" [value]="frequency.id">
        {{frequency.label}}
      </option>
    </select>
```

You can log and check using `(change)` event in your select statement as

```
<select id="frequency" (change)="changed(frequency)">
....
```

which is available in the below demo plunker

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/qBfz8hVszr71AqySNeIN?p=preview)**

Comment: This does not appear to solve the issue.  I can make this work when I declare everything inside of the same file.  The problem comes in from using the TemplateURL: attribute on the @component decorator. As soon as I point to the external file, everything breaks.  It's almost like the frequencies object in the export class isn't being sent to the my external HTML file.

Comment: found the problem! sneaky sneaky.  I forgot to set name ="frequencies".  Original code works. I'm just a ditz.  Could kick myself in the shin.  Thank you for the help.  I think I need to try the rubber duck debug next time.

Comment: Oopssss guess no one would make such a mistake. So my answer turns useless?

Comment: not useless. It got the gears spinning in a new direction.  Seeing the error messages I got against the new error messages clicked on the lights.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Cool then happy coding :)